# python list of tuples to javascript array of arrays

Tags: javascript, python

I have a list of tuples in python

```
[('abc','state','fsf',val), ('pqr','state','efg',val2)]
```

I want to convert them into javascript array of arrays.

I tried this

```
jdump = json.dumps(lis_of_tup) #in python 
and tried 
JSON.stringify(name)
alert(name + ' ' + typeof(name)) // this is returning a string
```

When I called split on name and caled item[0] its giving me 'abc' instead of `('abc','state','fsf',val)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python, I do

```
data = [('abc','state','fsf', "val"), ('pqr','state','efg', "val2")]
import json
print json.dumps(data)
```

**Output**

```
[["abc", "state", "fsf", "val"], ["pqr", "state", "efg", "val2"]]
```

And then I do this in javascript

```
data ='[["abc", "state", "fsf", "val"], ["pqr", "state", "efg", "val2"]]'
arrayOfArrays = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(arrayOfArrays);
```

and this gives

```
[ [ 'abc', 'state', 'fsf', 'val' ],
  [ 'pqr', 'state', 'efg', 'val2' ] ]
```

which is an array of arrays and when I do

```
console.log(arrayOfArrays[0]);
```

it gives

```
[ 'abc', 'state', 'fsf', 'val' ]
```