# Convert utf string ftom python to javascript dictionary

Tags: javascript, python, json

I am trying to pass value from Python ta Javascript (simple JSON) but when I try I cannot create, probably because u' for UTF in python

```
{'username': u'Tester1', 'age': 0L}
```

How to convert this string to javascript dictionary ?
I have tried JSON.parse, eval("(" + json + ")") but it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a Python object instead of JSON.

On the Python side, convert this to JSON first:

```
import json

json_value = json.dumps(python_object)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> python_object = {'username': u'Tester1', 'age': 0L}
>>> print json.dumps(python_object)
{"username": "Tester1", "age": 0}
```

The latter you can load into JavaScript with `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: I happened to provide a similar solution today http://stackoverflow.com/a/19354394/1903116